# PHP Use Declared array Variable inside already Declared Array

Tags: php, array, variables, post-class

i have created one class in which i declared public associative array.

```
class test{
public $basicCols= array(
      array('title'=>'KEY', 'field'=>'slug','options'=>$optList),
      array('title'=>'KEY', 'field'=>'slug'),
}

public $optList= array("one"=>"One","two"=>"Two");

}
```

But when i execute code its giving me error. 
I tried

```
$this->$optList
$this->optList
$optlist
```

is there any other way to declare variable inside variable in class. thank you in advance.

Comment: `$this->` is only used **inside the class** itself (so in its methods). In this case you need to instantiate the class `$foo = new test(); $foo->optList;` or make it static and access via `test::$optList`. Have [you read the docu on classes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)?

Comment: Yes i read the docs. i know how to used method in class. i want to divided public Variables in parts as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a generic PHP question than anything to do with WordPress, but I'd suggest setting the value in the constructor:

```
class test {
    public $basicCols;

    public $optList = array( 'one' => 'One', 'two' => 'Two' );

    function __construct() {
        $this->basicCols = array(
            array( 'title' => 'KEY', 'field' => 'slug', 'options' => $this->optList ),
            array( 'title' => 'KEY', 'field' => 'slug' )
        );
    }
}
```